# How to get inner datas of axios.get response reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have below Array response from my API but I can't get inner or specific data from it.

Here's my code for getting response from API.

```
const [dataSystem, setdataSystem] = useState([])
const getDependentSystems = async() => {
  const response = await axios.get('/API' + ID)
  console.log('LIST OF SYSTEM', response.data)
  console.log('ID', response.data.ID)
  setdataSystem(response.data)
}
```

Here's the result of `console.log('LIST OF SYSTEM', response.data)`

[image]

What I want to do is to get the result of `ID`, `SYSTEMID`, `etc.` but upon `console.log('ID',response.data.ID)` I got `undefined` result.

Hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

response.data is an array, response.data is not returning an object {}, your API responded directly with the array []

```
setdataSystem(response.data)
```

Is already setting your state as the returned array

```
console.log('ID', response.data.ID)
```

Is undefined because you can only access the array element with an index

So the following would be defined:

```
console.log('ID', response.data[0].ID)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer @iunfixit and can you also provide sample code because I'm lost. In addition, when I get the specific data that I want, I will save it to an array so I will not specifically get an ID. Thank you

Comment: I updated it,  you're already saving it as an array, it only returns undefined in your console.log because you don't specify an array index, like `response.data[0]` for example

Comment: If that's not clear I can change it to a more specific example depending on what you want to do with that array

Comment: I'm getting the specific ID based on your answer @iunfixit, however I don't want to just get one ID, I want to on the response and save the IDs on another array. I want to display all IDs that I get to my Edit form. Thank you